# how to ignore soft delete in laravel multiple unique columns in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, unique, laravel-5.3

I have been doing a project right now. In this I am stuck. All I want that to ignore soft delete of laravel in my validation that has unique column of name, parent_id.

For example :
Suppose A & B is category. I want that If C is a subcategory of A then no other C data is not written in A. But C can be written in B category.

I also want that If a User SoftDeletes the data then he can insert same data with the same name and with the same category.

My Table is

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->string('name');
  $table->integer('parent_id')->nullable()->default(0);
  $table->integer('admin_id')->nullable()->default(0);
  $table->boolean('active')->nullable()->default(1);
  $table->unique(array('parent_id', 'name', 'deleted_at'));
  $table->rememberToken();
  $table->timestamps();
  $table->softDeletes();
});
```

My Store method is

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $this->validate($request, [
    'category' => 'required|unique:categories,parent_id,NULL,name,NULL,id,deleted_at,NULL',
    'parent' => 'required',
    '_token'   => '',
  ]);

  try {
    $category = New Category();
    $category->name = $request['category'];
    $category->parent_id = $request['parent'];
    $category->remember_token = $request['_token'];
    $category->save();
    $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Sub Category Successfully Created!');
    return redirect('subcategory');    
  } catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
    return redirect()->back()
                     ->with('status','<strong>'.$category.' already exist!</strong>');
  }            
}
```

My model is

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Category extends Model
{
  use Notifiable;
  use SoftDeletes;
  protected $fillable = [
    'category',
  ];
  protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

The Error is 
[image: It Gives This error]

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
‘category' => 'required|unique:categories,parent_id,NULL,id,deleted_at,NULL,name,’.$request['category'],
```

For more details, separate the parameters into pairs:

1. [categories, parent_id]

   - This means the unique rule should be implemented in the table `categories`, column `parent_id`.
   - If the position of parent_id is same with the left “category”, it can be ignore. E.g

     ‘name’ => ‘unique:products,name’ **can be simplified to**

     ‘name’ => ‘unique:products’.
2. [NULL, id]

   - The unique rule should exclude the item where id is null.
   - It looks like nonsense, because id cannot be null.
   - But this pair is a special one. In the Laravel unique validation (vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php:getUniqueIds()), it defines parameters the third position a special one. As long as you want to attach other constraints after, you need this. Just like a format.
   - Once again, this is a special pair. In the update validation, you can pass in the id to ignore the updated item itself.
3. [deleted_at, NULL]

   - The unique rule should implement in the scope where deleted_at is null.
   - The is where you consider the soft delete.
   - You can use NOT_NULL to mean the opposite.

Therefore, the final scope to implement the unique rule is the results get from below query:

```
    Select count(*) from categories
    where id is not null
    and deleted_at is null
    and name is ??$request['category']??
```

If the count(*) is 0, then the validation get through. Otherwise, fail.

You can have as many constraints as you need after the third pair. such as:

=> 4. [active, true]

=> 5. [name, hello], you can use '!hello' to mean where the name is not 'hello'

Comment: The pair #2 is a special and only one. You cannot add another [value, key] pair after that. That's whey the `NULL, name, id, NULL` does not work.

Comment: Why in the pair #2 instead of key,value is value,key. I mean in toher cases we do "name", "SomeName", but why is not like "id", NULL in the second pair?

Comment: @JacoboTapia It is from the source code --  getUniqueIds() function:  ```$idColumn = $parameters[3] ?? 'id';```         I don't why it is not [id, Null] and I agree it is quite wired. You can put other columns here. For example, ["female", "gender"] will exclude all records where gender is "female".

Answer (score -1):

Could it be you validation string is not right? 
Shouldn't it be

> required|unique:categories,parent_id,NULL,name,NULL,deleted_at,NULL

Comment: tried but not give my expected result. It shows me error that describe above @veelen